# JQ: setdiff of two arrays

Tags: jq, set-difference

If I have an object with two arrays containing unique values in it

```
{"all":["A","B","C","ABC"],"some":["B","C"]}
```

How can I find `.all - .some`?

In this case I am looking for `["A","ABC"]`

Comment: Don't you already have what you're looking for? `.all - .some`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@Jeff Mercado blew my mind! I didn't know array subtraction was allowed...

```
echo -n '{"all":["A","B","C","ABC"],"some":["B","C"]}' | jq '.all-.some'
```

yields

```
[
  "A",
  "ABC"
]
```

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for a similar solution but with the requirement that the arrays were being generated dynamically. Below solution just does the expected

```
array1=$(jq -e '')  // jq expression goes here
array2=$(jq -e '')  // jq expression goes here

array_diff=$(jq -n --argjson array1 "$array1" --argjson array2 "$array2" 
'{"all": $array1,"some":$array2} | .all-.some' )
```

Comment: you could just do `$array1-$array2` at the end

Comment: A small improvement, allowing to get changes on both sides at the same time
`jq -n --argjson a "$a" --argjson b "$b" '{"a < b":($a-$b),"a > b":($b-$a)}'`

Answer (score 1):

While [- Array Subtraction](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Subtraction:-) is the best approach for this, here is another solution using [del](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#del(path_expression)) and [indices](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#indices(s)):

```
. as $d | .all | del(.[ indices($d.some[])[] ])
```

It may be of help when you want to know which elements were removed.  For example with the sample data and the `-c` (compact output) option, the following filter

```
  . as $d
| .all
| [indices($d.some[])[]] as $found
| del(.[ $found[] ])
| "all", $d.all, "some", $d.some, "removing indices", $found, "result", .
```

produces

```
"all"
["A","B","C","ABC"]
"some"
["B","C"]
"removing indices"
[1,2]
"result"
["A","ABC"]
```